# undefined method `provider' for nil:NilClass, RSpec, OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I'm trying to test an authenticated controller with RSpec and OmniAuth. I've followed the [integration testing](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing) guide on their wiki. When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error:
       where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.picture = auth.info.image
        user.save!
       end

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `provider' for nil:NilClass
```

All relevant code is provided in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Carpetfizz/5dad0f0f8d5abe79cbe39d6d226cd5e0). My hunch is that the mock auth hash isn't being set somehow but I have no way of verifying that. I configure OmniAuth in `config/environments/test.rb` as shown in the Gist, and I'm pretty sure that file is ran when the application boots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues that I see. For one, you're not testing the action of signing-in. You're hitting a controller action with oauth data in the request and expecting it to pass authentication. Oauth data isn't like an API key and won't let you auto sign-in like that. You have to hit the specific signin action provided by omniauth which then sets-up your user's session. This should be tested on its own to confirm that your whole oauth sign-in strategy works as expected. If you're testing controller actions that are not directly related to the act of oauth signins, then you should be using [the devise test helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)) to sign-in users before running tests that would require authentication.

Also, you don't want to be setting the `OmniAuth` configuration in an environment initialiser. The documentation suggests, and what I do myself, is set the configuration down in the tests. For one thing, this allows you to test different kinds of scenarios. For example, this is how I test that my omniauth callback controllers are working and doing what I want:

```
context 'with valid google credentials' do
  # this should actually be created in a factory
  let(:provider) { :google_oauth2 }
  let(:oauth) { OmniAuth::AuthHash.new provider: provider, uid: '1234' }
  before do
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[provider] = oauth
  end

  it 'creates a new user' do
    expect { visit "/users/auth/#{provider}" }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm testing it out. I get an undefined method `visit` error. I only have `require 'rails_helper'` and the `rspec-rails` gem installed

Comment: Just installed `capybara` as it seems to define the `visit` method, yet I am still getting the error.

Comment: Did you add `require 'capybara/rails'` to your `rails_helper.rb`?